# React-Native & Redux - doens't have 'index.js' entry file

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I've created my app with `react-native` and `expo` thru `expo init <project name>`.

once I've made my app.
I need to deploy `redux` in my app.

Once I study about redux, in order to deploy it into my react app, I need to wrap `index.js` file with `<Provider>`.

However, when I created my app with expo, menu looks all [image]

I doesn't have `index.js` file.

So instead I wrap Provider in `App.js` like below.

```
 return (
    <Provider stroe={store}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {isLoggedIn ? <LogggedInNav /> : <LoggedOutNav />}
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </Provider>
```

is that okay?
and why I don't have `index.js` file as an entry file?

Comment: The spelling of store in  <Provider /> tag is incorrect. Apart from that everything is fine. It should work. You can test by adding some test state in reducer and accessing it in your project